# How do I make a Django ModelForm menu item selected by default?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working on a Django app. One of my models, "User", includes a "gender" field, as defined below:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True)
```

I am using a ModelForm to generate a "new user" HTML form. My Google-fu seems to be failing me -- how can I make this HTML form have the "Male" item selected by default in the drop-down box? (i.e. so `selected="selected"` for this item.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need a blank form with a default value selected, then pass an 'initial' dictionary to the constructor of your model form using the name of your field as the key:

```
form = MyModelForm (initial={'gender':'M'})
```

-OR-

You can override certain attributes of a ModelForm using the declarative nature of the Forms API.  However, this is probably a little cumbersome for this use case and I mention it only to show you that you can do it.   You may find other uses for this in the future.

```
class MyModelForm (forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField (choices=..., initial='M', ...)
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
```

-OR-

If you want a ModelForm that is bound to a particular instance of your model, you can pass an 'instance' of your model which causes Django to pull the selected value from that model.

```
form = MyModelForm (instance=someinst)
```

Comment: I actually just found out that passing an instance of the model as you did in your answer doesn't make Django show the selected value in HTML.  It works for text input fields just fine, but I need it for select input as well.  Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: @GChorn It should work for select fields too so there may be something else awry. I'd recommend creating a new question and posting the relevant code so you can get more folks taking a look.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the reply, yes I actually did this yesterday but no answers yet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16056045/1256700

Answer (score 8):

Surely `default` will do the trick?

e.g.

```
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M', null=True)
```