# Django ModelForm ChoiceField not displaying instance data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` class in which I set a couple of the fields as `ChoiceField`.  For one of my views, I'd like to create a form from my `ModelForm` class that pulls from an instance of my model in the database (like so):

```
form = MyModel(instance=model_instance)
```

When I do this and then render the form in a template, I've noticed that most of the fields are pre-populated with values pulled from the model instance, which is what I want.  However, this isn't the case for two `ChoiceField` fields.  These render as drop-down select menus with no specific option selected.

What's strange is if I don't define those two fields as `ChoiceField`-type in my ModelForm class, they render as normal text input fields in HTML and pre-populate using the database values.  But when I define them so they show up as select-option input fields in HTML, nothing is pre-selected.  Can I change this so that the values from the database are pre-selected?

**EDIT:** As requested here is the code for my model and form:

```
class App(models.Model):
    CODES = (
        (u'a',u'annual'),
        (u'm',u'monthly'),
        (u'w',u'weekly')
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CODES)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)


class AppForm(ModelForm):
    CODES = (
        (u'',u'Please select code'),
        (u'a',u'annual'),
        (u'm',u'monthly'),
        (u'w',u'weekly')
    )
    TIMES = (
        (u'00:00',u'All Day'),
        (u'12:00',u'Noon')
    )
    start_time = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=TIMES)
    end_time = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=TIMES)
    code = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CODES, label='Type')

    class Meta:
        model = App
```

Interestingly, `code` field has the model instance value preselected just fine when rendered as HTML.  I wonder if having the `choices` argument in the model definition makes the difference here?

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that if I pull up an `App` instance in the `python manage.py shell` like so:

```
a = App.objects.get(id=16)
a.start_time
```

I get a value like `datetime.time(12, 0)`.  But in the Django admin, when I'm looking at all of the `App` instances, all of them show `(None)` under `start_time` and `end_time`.  Why would that be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a Django ModelForm menu item selected by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624265/how-do-i-make-a-django-modelform-menu-item-selected-by-default) and many more.

Comment: could you post the code to your model and the form. Thanks.

Comment: @Hedde, not looking to have a default selected option.  I want the selected option to come from the object instance.  You'll notice I actually posted a comment below the accepted answer to that other question precisely because it didn't work for me.

Comment: To define a dynamic initial value override the init method of the form to set the default value by the given instance value

Comment: @Hedde, thank you for the suggestion.  I edited my question to include the code for my model and form, and now I'm wondering why the instance value is shown in my form's `code` field but not in the other two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your update : your times strings match default time string HH:MM format. Just like a user would enter them from website manually 12:00. The values get parsed and turned into time at model save (at validating really).

And when you load model - then of course the initial values loaded from object match the field's (models.TimeField) type.

If you replace your TIMES with

```
    (datetime.time(0,0),u'All Day'),
    (datetime.time(12,0),u'Noon')
```

your troubles should be over.

Alan

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the answer, I actually came to the same conclusion right before I saw your response (I actually came back to "answer" my own question!).  Interestingly, one thing I discovered as I was fiddling with the problem is, if you create a set of `CHOICES` in the model definition that uses string representations of times, it throws an error when trying to save one of these values in a form (it didn't do so when said `CHOICES` were provided in the `AppForm` definition as above).  But the weirdest thing is, it didn't throw an error when attempting to save `'00:00'`, only `12:00`.

Comment: If you provide choices in a form, then you should probably use forms.TypedChoiceField with argument 'coerce' set to datetime.time https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield. And that should fix that error.